How to handle the communication Between Presenters for Login and Main Windows in MVP Architecture with Continuing Application Execution?
I'm developing a WinForms application using the MVP (Model-View-Presenter) architecture. In my architecture, I have separate projects for the main application logic (ProjectMain), views (ProjectMain.Views), and presenters (ProjectMain.Presenters).
The application consists of a login window and a main window, each with its corresponding presenter:
Login Window:

View: LoginForm
Presenter: LoginPresenter

Main Window:

View: MainForm
Presenter: MainPresenter

After a successful login, I want to close the login window and open the main window. However, even after closing the main window, I need the application to continue running in the background.
How can I implement communication between the login presenter and the main presenter to achieve this, considering my MVP architecture?
I'm considering using events, but I'm unsure about the best way to set this up. Should the login presenter raise an event when the login is successful, and the main presenter subscribe to this event to open the main window? Or is there a better approach?
Additionally, how can I ensure that the application continues running in the background even after the main window is closed?
Any advice, code examples, or best practices for handling this scenario within an MVP architecture would be greatly appreciated!
